# Typing a custom useRef hook for any type of HTML element

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, ref

I'm still a bit new to Typescript and my goal is to create a custom `React.useRef` hook in Typescript that returns a ref. I would like this ref to be typed for any HTML element and not just buttons only. I'm running into issues of typing this custom hook properly.

Here's my hook:

```
type CustomRefHook = (dependencies?: string | boolean | number[]) => React.MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | null>;

const useCustomRefHook: CustomRefHook = (...dependencies) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... do stuff
  }, dependencies)

  return ref;
}
```

For now, the majority of my use cases for this hook would be for buttons but I would like to eventually expand this to any sort of HTML element. I've tried using `HTMLElement` instead of `HTMLButtonElement` , however I get a type error of:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.
```

whenever I try to attach this ref to a button. Using `HTMLButtonElement` quiets the Typescript errors, but again I'd like this hook to be able to handle any type of HTML element.

Comment: You will need to use a generic for the element type.

Comment: What would that look like? 

I've tried something like: 
`type CustomRefHook = <T>(dependencies?: string | boolean | number[]) => React.MutableRefObject<T>;`

Comment: Yeah that's basically it.  I'll type up an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the `ref` needs to exactly match the DOM element that it is attached to, so you need to use a generic to specify the element type.

Since `useCustomRefHook` is now a generic function, it makes more sense to declare the typings inline rather than as a separate type `CustomRefHook`.

I have allowed this hook to accept `any` value of `T`, but you could use `T extends HTMLElement` if you just want it to apply to HTML elements.  That might be important depending on the contents of "do stuff" inside your `useEffect`.  If "do stuff" requires anything specific about `T`, then you need to make sure that `T` extends something with the required properties/methods.

```
import React, { MutableRefObject, DependencyList, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useCustomRefHook = <T extends any>( dependencies: DependencyList = [] ): MutableRefObject<T | null> => {

  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... do stuff
  }, dependencies);

  return ref;
};
```

The hook returns a `MutableRefObject<T | null>` based on the generic `T`.  The value of `T` cannot possibly be inferred from the arguments, so you will need to specify the generic every time that you call it.

```
const Test = () => {
  const ref = useCustomRefHook<HTMLButtonElement>();

  return <button ref={ref} />;
};
```

Comment: Q: How would I extract this out into a type declaration? 


`type CustomRefType = <T extends HTMLElement>(dependencies: React.DependencyList) => React.MutableRefObject<T | null>`


`const useCustomRefHook: CustomRefType = (dependencies = []) => {
  const ref = useRef<T | null>(null);
}`

I get an error saying `"Cannot find name 'T'"`. How would I provide the generic type down to the `React.useRef`? @Linda Paiste

Comment: You can’t really extract it out when the function itself is generic.

Comment: Got it. Ok that makes sense